# Javascript variable value in a class of an element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put the value of javascript variable inside a class of `</a>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sp-pt-151').countdown('2016/09/02', function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%n'));
        var dd = event.strftime('%n');
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#"class="avatar-container p-dd personal">
     <img src="images/train.png" alt="" width:"100px" hieght:"100px" class="avatar"/>
</a>
```

As you can see in the "a" element class `p-dd`. I want the value of `dd` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
$('#sp-pt-151').countdown('2016/09/02', function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%n'));
    var dd = event.strftime('%n');

    $('a.p-dd').removeClass('p-dd').addClass('p-'+dd);

});
```

I suppose you have either single `a` element with that class, or you want to update class of all `a`s with `p-dd` class.